# Alias to ssh and cd into a specific directory

Tags: terminal, ssh, alias

I want an alias to SSH into another machine and then CD into a specific directory.

I try:

```
alias appl="ssh 9@lon.orb.com; cd /opt/tomcat/instances/"
```

It does not work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because the `cd` is executed on your local machine
when the `ssh` does terminate.

Here is the way to do it:

```
alias appl="ssh 9@lon.orb.com 'cd /opt/tomcat/instances ; exec ${SHELL} -i'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the cd should work in the remote machine, then this cannot work.

You could change your `~/.bash_profile` to do this cd for every login or just from certain machines.